# scikit-learn - Using a single string with RandomForestClassifier.predict()?

Tags: scikit-learn, text-classification

I'm an sklearn dummy...  I'm trying to predict the label for a given string from a RandomForestClassifier() fitted with text, labels.

It's obvious I don't know how to use predict() with a single string.  The reason I'm using reshape() is because I got this error some time ago "Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample."

How can I predict the label of a single text string?

## The script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
''' Read a txt file consisting of '<label>: <long string of text>'
    to use as a model for predicting the label for a string
'''

from argparse import ArgumentParser
import json
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder


def main(args):
    '''
    args: Arguments obtained by _Get_Args()
    '''

    print('Loading data...')
    # Load data from args.txtfile and split the lines into
    # two lists (labels, texts).
    data = open(args.txtfile).readlines()
    labels, texts = ([], [])
    for line in data:
        label, text = line.split(': ', 1)
        labels.append(label)
        texts.append(text)

    # Print a list of unique labels
    print(json.dumps(list(set(labels)), indent=4))

    # Instantiate a CountVectorizer class and git the texts
    # and labels into it.
    cv = CountVectorizer(
            stop_words='english',
            strip_accents='unicode',
            lowercase=True,
            )
    matrix = cv.fit_transform(texts)
    encoder = LabelEncoder()
    labels = encoder.fit_transform(labels)
    rf = RandomForestClassifier()
    rf.fit(matrix, labels)

    # Try to predict the label for args.string.
    prediction = Predict_Label(args.string, cv, rf)
    print(prediction)


def Predict_Label(string, cv, rf):
    '''
    string: str() - A string of text
    cv: The CountVectorizer class
    rf: The RandomForestClassifier class
    '''

    matrix = cv.fit_transform([string])
    matrix = matrix.reshape(1, -1)
    try:
        prediction = rf.predict(matrix)
    except Exception as E:
        print(str(E))
    else:
        return prediction


def _Get_Args():
    parser = ArgumentParser(description='Learn labels from text')
    parser.add_argument('-t', '--txtfile', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('-s', '--string', required=True)
    return parser.parse_args()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = _Get_Args()
    main(args)
```

The actual learning data text file is 43663 lines long but a sample is in small_list.txt which consists of lines each in the format: `<label>: <long text string>`

## The error is noted in the Exception output:

```
$ ./learn.py -t small_list.txt -s 'This is a string that might have something to do with phishing or fraud'
Loading data...
[
    "Vulnerabilities__Unknown",
    "Vulnerabilities__MSSQL Browsing Service",
    "Fraud__Phishing",
    "Fraud__Copyright/Trademark Infringement",
    "Attacks and Reconnaissance__Web Attacks",
    "Vulnerabilities__Vulnerable SMB",
    "Internal Report__SBL Notify",
    "Objectionable Content__Russian Federation Objectionable Material",
    "Malicious Code/Traffic__Malicious URL",
    "Spam__Marketing Spam",
    "Attacks and Reconnaissance__Scanning",
    "Malicious Code/Traffic__Unknown",
    "Attacks and Reconnaissance__SSH Brute Force",
    "Spam__URL in Spam",
    "Vulnerabilities__Vulnerable Open Memcached",
    "Malicious Code/Traffic__Sinkhole",
    "Attacks and Reconnaissance__SMTP Brute Force",
    "Illegal content__Child Pornography"
]
Number of features of the model must match the input. Model n_features is 2070 and input n_features is 3 
None
```

Comment: It seems that you are training the model using a number `n` of features/variables and then you are trying to predict using a testing sample that DOES NOT have `n` features. Can you add the data?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the vocabulary of the first CountVectorizer (cv) and use to transform the new single text before predict.

```
...

cv = CountVectorizer(
        stop_words='english',
        strip_accents='unicode',
        lowercase=True,
        )

matrix = cv.fit_transform(texts)
encoder = LabelEncoder()
labels = encoder.fit_transform(labels)
rf = RandomForestClassifier()
rf.fit(matrix, labels)

# Try to predict the label for args.string.
cv_new = CountVectorizer(
        stop_words='english',
        strip_accents='unicode',
        lowercase=True,
        vocabulary=cv.vocabulary_
        )
prediction = Predict_Label(args.string, cv_new, rf)
print(prediction)

...
```